# WooCommerce. Как разрешить добавлять товары в корзину, которых нет в наличии

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Очень прошу помочь!!! Перерыл весь интернет и нигде не нашел решения (впервые такое). Всего-то нужно разрешить добавлять и покупать товары, которых нет в наличии.

Вроде все просто, нашел, где добавлению товаров мешает исключение в class-wc-cart.php, а именно:

```
// Stock check - only check if we're managing stock and backorders are not allowed
            if ( ! $product_data->is_in_stock() ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add &quot;%s&quot; to the cart because the product is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) );
            }
```

Не могу понять, как отключить данное исключение через функцию (просто удалить не пойдет!). Пришел к этому:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom',5,6 );

function woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() ) {
$product_data = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $cart_item_data = (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id );
    $cart_id        = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
    $cart_item_key  = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );

    // Stock check - only check if we're managing stock and backorders are not allowed
            if ( ! $product_data->is_in_stock() ) {
                continue;
            }
    return false;
}
```

Но не работает. Все перепробовал. Как отменить выполнение исключения - throw new Exception?

Answer (score 3):

Не надо издеваться над кодом. Включите предзаказы в админке.

Поле "разрешить предзаказы" появится только после того, как поставите галочку в "Управлять запасами".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаете лучше ничего не пишите. Не засоряйте тему ненужными ответами. Еще раз: мне нужно разрешить покупать товары которых нет в наличии !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Не спец, но можно попробовать переопределить функцию/хук, что то вроде

```
if(remove_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom',5)){
    function my_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variation = array(), $cart_item_data = array() ) {
        $product_data = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $cart_item_data = (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id );
        $cart_id        = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
        $cart_item_key  = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );
        return false;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom', 5, 6);
}
```

В общем удалить хук который установлен, и навесить свой, дублируя код и удалить ту часть которая не нужна, но что то мне подсказывает что проверок куда больше чем в одном месте.

Comment: Проверка одна, так как при прямом удалении в class-wc-cart.php товар добавляется в корзину! Переопределять функцию пробовал, но ничего не получается!!!!

Comment: @Евгений где пробовали? как пробовали?

Comment: Есть соображающие люди на этом форуме????? Какой-то бесполезный форум!

Comment: @Евгений это не форум, и тут нет годалок, никто не будет тратить свое время, что бы решить вашу задачу от и до, не хотите ничего делать, вперед на фриланс биржи

Comment: Пока ни одного дельного совета. Видать специалистов здесь нет. Только время на поболтать. Зато здесь тратят время на подсказки, которые действительно смешные и решений куча, но разжевывают от и до.

Comment: Хотя бы кто нибудь ответил возможно ли отменить выполнение исключения в блоке try через функцию в function.php?

Comment: Я с вами общаюсь, даю мысли на размышления, и это вы мне благодарны так? от сюда мало у кого есть желание тратить свое время. Ответ на ваш второй вопрос - никак. Единый путь заменить класс, функцию, исходники. Дельный совет - потратьте время на изучения основ, потом рассуждайте о людях которые тратят свое время на вас.

Comment: Опять бла, бла, бла. нет времени - не тратьте на никакой ответ.

Comment: Желаю вам того же от ношения. Идите учитесь

Comment: Хватит засорять тему. Есть реально знающие люди? Как отключить эту проверку? Просьба не писать ниочемные ответы!!!

Answer (score 0):

Предложу вариант, а то пост выдаётся поисковиками, а решения нет в столь жаркой дискуссии.

```
function allow_purchasable($cond, $instance)
{
    return true;
}

/*
 * Для товаров которых нет в наличии
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'allow_purchasable', 10, 2);

/*
 * Для товара у которого цена 0
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'allow_purchasable', 10, 2);

// С другими условия и фильтрами можно ознакомится в коде класса WC_Product
```

Проверено на товарах у которых не указана цена и нет в наличии.