# Как отменить выполнение исключения - throw new Exception?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как отменить выполнение исключения - throw new Exception?
Имеется следующее условие:

```
if ( ! $product_data->is_in_stock() ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add &quot;%s&quot; to the cart because the product is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) );
            }
```

Можно изменить запись, дополнить его, но Как его отменить???

Comment: возможно удалить?)

Comment: @Bookin согласно [предыдущему вопросу автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684888/223826), удалять нельзя! :)

Comment: При обновлении woocomerce все слетит. Нужно через функцию.

Comment: @teran в предыдущем было удалено исключение и написано что не работает)

Comment: Есть специалисты??? Подскажите

Comment: Да! Только ответов нет. Просто мусор в обоих темах

Comment: @Евгений такой же мусор, как и ваш вопрос

Comment: Смотрю здесь могут дать вопрос только на вопросы типа как убрать сообщение, как изменить название какой-нибудь кнопки, как изменить стиль кнопки и т.д. А мой вопрос уже в клин бросил и его конечно лучше в мусор. Специалисты блин.